# Плагин chrome: добраться до div, который подгружается ajax-ом

Tags: google-chrome, плагин

Здравствуйте, уважаемые. Не могли бы Вы подсказать, как добраться до `DIV`'a, который подгружается `ajax`'ом? И как вообще мониторить появление этого блока? Не таймер же ставить?! или...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[[@hase](/users/12059/hase)](/users/12059/hase) там сначала нужно манифест вроде прописать, а потом получить документ (я для `firefox` писал расширение, там вообще по дефолту глобального `window` не существует, [нашел документацию](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/windows.html)).

[[@Sexy Girl](/users/8271/sexy-girl)](/users/8271/sexy-girl) вам бы следовало почитать документацию и найти пункт, как получить это "рабочее окно", где находится сайт. 
По поводу отловки новых элементов - если можно перехватывать `ajax` запросы - то после просто смотреть содержимое ответа. Если нельзя перехватывать, то просто вешаем событие [`DOMNodeInserted`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/DOM/Events/Mutation_events?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM%2FMutation_events) куда-нибудь на элемент или документ.

Comment: @Sexy Girl в общем-то не сложно. Я бы добавил то, что плагины это одно (вроде флеша, работает через NPAPI), а расширения - другое (типа адблока, у вас тоже расширение получается). Также обновил пост, добавил пару наводящих ссылок.

Comment: Можно не парится и писать usescript, так как плагин нужно писать под каждый браузер, а к ишаку так вообще помойму не напишешь(не факт)
А так и там и там есть доступ к windows, просто со своими заморочками.

Comment: Да я плагин чисто для себя пишу, для удобства работы

Answer (score 0):

Подгруженные/созданные элементы очень даже хорошо видно, ПКМ - Просмотр кода элемента

Comment: ТС вообще не о том спрашивал.

Comment: Доступ через js(плагин)? так же легко все получить но только после того как загруженные элементы уже вставлены. Проверять есть ли элемент, если есть работать с ним.
События так же легко бинтуются. Нечего сложного нет.

Comment: Да, через js пытаюсь подключится. С такой проблемой столкнулась, что Js функции видеть отказывается, тина неизвестная функция, сам файл с JS подключала через манифест

Comment: @lampa переведите пожалуйста свой комент в ответ, я его отмечу. Спасибо всем